# photon interpretation of second harmonic generation

Tags: photons, non-linear-optics

Non linear materials can be responsible for second harmonic generation when subject to electromagnetic fields with high enough intensity.

I simply want to know if there is a particule interpretation of this mechanism? Is a photon with energy twice as large as the original photon created in the process?

Comment: "Is a photon with energy twice as large as the original photon created in the process?"  Wouldn't this violate conservation of energy?

Comment: I think non linear medium are medium in which exchange of energy may occur. For example, a laser may constitute a non linear optical medium where the energy is coming from the pumping mechanism.

Comment: Look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second-harmonic_generation and the 1st picture. If the photon density is high (i.e. high intensity) two of them may "combine" using virtual states.

Comment: Alright thanks. I suppose the answer in a word is "yes".